Can I subtract textbox string Group?
enter image description here
I have a textbox group of
Dim TextBoxes1() As TextBox = {Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4, Player5}
I want to subtract this textbox group from TextBoxes1() and put the output into outputTextBoxes() textbox. like Image.
Dim outputTextBoxes() As TextBox = {Player6Run, Player7Run, Player8Run, Player9Run, Player10Run}
enter image description here
I have wirtten this code. But its not working. Is there any Idea? TIA
  Dim yourColumn1TextBoxes() As TextBox = {Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4, Player5}

  Dim outputTextBoxes() As TextBox = {Player6Run, Player7Run, Player8Run, Player9Run, Player10Run}




  outputTextBoxes() = yourColumn1TextBoxes() - outputTextBoxes()


This doesn't look like VBA. Change your tag accordingly please

this is from visual basic.

@user26532807 Visual Basic for Application (VBA) does not allow single statement declaration and setting of variables, only for Constants.  (i.e. Dim varString As String = "Test" will fail, but Const constString As String = "Test" will work) — although, you can use a Colon to combine statements on one line (Dim varString As String: varString = "Test"). That is also not how you define Arrays in VBA either (varVariant = {"This", "Is", "Some", "Text"} will fail, but varVariant = Array("This", "Is", "Some", "Text") will work)  So, as Haluk said: is this VBA, VB.net, VBScript, VB6…?
